# Understanding JNDI for use with Java Batch Applications

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I have spent a couple of days reading up on JNDI how to use it, I have a few questions that I'm not 100% clear on.

Background:

I would like to configure a number of standalone Java Batch programs that will use JNDI to retrieve properties from a web server (Tomcat 7). From reading, my understanding that this is possible by specifying items in the server.xml

```
<GlobalNamingResources>....</GlobalNamingResources>
```

Testing:

My testing of this so far has been to create a proof of concept type setup. I have configured a Tomcat server with the following property in the GlobalNamingResorces.

```
<Environment name="testProp" value="Hello GlobalNamingResources"
         type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

I have created a simple Java program that is attempting to retrieve this property from tomcat. This is failing with a javax.naming.NoInitialContextException Exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "http://localhost:9080");

    try {
        InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext(props);
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

        Object object = envCtx.lookup("testProp");

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me if what I am trying to do is possible?

Am I on the right track to complete this?

For the Inital Context Creation, is this something that needs to be in my Java Batch or something that is located on the server?

Comment: Not sure this is possible in Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure accessing JNDI remotely is possible in Tomcat.  If [this](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q22) is up to date then apparently not.  The question "Can I access Tomcat's JNDI remotely" might be a better question to ask than asking about Java Batch (if I'm understanding correctly);  you might get a quicker response.

But...since you're already using Tomcat you might be interested in the upcoming TomEE release which targets EE 7 support including Java Batch support.  Another alternative is the product I work on, [WebSphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-eclipse/).

Comment: Yep you are right, this is not possible with Tomcat. The only way I was able to get this working was to use an alternative server deployment. I ended up using [Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Remote+JNDI+Configuration).

Tomcat was preferred as it was the Server type we were already using

Comment: Glad to hear.  I'm not totally following the versioning but I think it's TomEE 2.0.0 that will include BatchEE (thus Batch support).